# MySQLi - select sub menu item from db if parentid same as top menu item id

Tags: php, select, menu, mysqli, parent

I have a menu with top and sub items. All the items, top and sub items have a unique "id" in the database and a "parentid". Top items, all have "parentid" "0" as value, sub items have "parentid" same as the "id" of the top item they correspond to..

Is there a way to select the menu from the db to look like this on the page?

Top Item 1 - My Own Sub Item 1, My Own Sub Item 2, My Own Sub Item 3

Top Item 2 - My Own Sub Item 1, My Own Sub Item 2, My Own Sub Item 3

Top Item 3 - My Own Sub Item 1, My Own Sub Item 2, My Own Sub Item 3

etc.

I am new to databases, I tried everything but I can't get what I want..
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Post your tried code.

Comment: How deep are the menus? can sub items have sub items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a parent child relation between the top menu and the sub items, so you need to create an extra column in the sub items table, say, `main_menu_id`, after doing this, you need to assign `id` of the main menu to the sub menu item in that column.

Later you will need a nested while loop using PHP and have to fetch the records accordingly.

```
/* Loop Top Items Starts
      Loop Inner Items (Fetch Sub Items Having ID Of The Main Item)
   Loop Top Items Ends
*/
```

1st Query

```
SELECT * FROM main_menu;
```

2nd Query (Nested In While Loop)

```
SELECT * FROM sub_menu WHERE main_menu_id = $looped_id;
```

Comment: A great read about hierarchical data in mysql: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @Jeroen Thank you for providing that, but as the OP specified that it's only upto 1 level, this answer will suffice his needs :)

Comment: Thanks, I got at least some idea now :)

Comment: @AdrianM. BTW `$looped_id` is the id which you will be looping outside(parent id) :)

Comment: @Mr. Alien: It wasn't really a comment on your answer, just some extra information he can maybe use in his future work ;) It also shows you how you can do it with one query which really is useful if a lot of first-level elements exist.

Comment: @Jeroen Indeed it's a good article, am reading it, thanks for sharing :)